# Java Spring - new ModelAndView adds "/" to URL

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring app that if a failure scenario is detected, it redirects the user to an error page with a code and description added as query strings.  So the code to set that in my service is:

```
redirectURL = "https://my.app.com";
serviceResponse.setRedirect_url(redirectURL + "?error_code=" + map.get("error_code")
        + "&error_description=" + URLEncoder.encode(map.get("error_description"), "UTF-8"));
```

I then send this back to my controller, where I return a new ModelAndView object with the URL

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + serviceResponse.getRedirect_url());
```

What I'm expecting my URL to look like is `https://www.my.app.com?error_code=001&error_description=This+is+a+failure+response`, but it looks like `https://www.my.app.com/?error_code=001&error_description=This+is+a+failure+response`

Is there a way I can specify not to add the `/`?

Comment: I think https://my.app.com?=error_code=001... is not a valid URL

Comment: You're right! That is my bad when I typed it in. It shows as `https://www.my.app.com/?error_code=001&error_description=This+is+a+failure+response`

Comment: The two URLs are equal

Comment: Yep, your code meets your expectations it seems

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus I am not on my A game today, I edited the body to reflect the correct URLs

Comment: Also, you could use Spring's RedirectAttributes object to pass parameters when redirecting.

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus Can that work with ModelAndView? I see examples online using this return a String like `redirect:/Hello`, but my method returns a ModelAndView

Comment: What kind of "view model" is it when there is no view at all?

Comment: Returning a String works similar to a ModelAndView. You could also pass 'redirect:/Hello' to a ModelAndView and it would work in the same way. And like @Antoniossss mentioned, you are not calling a view. What do you want to do when users are redirected to this URL?